# Java - array of counters to count specified objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, counter

I have a class with one field `int size`. I'm creating objects, for example: I created 2 objects of `size = 2` and 1 object of `size = 1` I want to control number of created objects of every size, so I'm trying to make an array of counters for every object, but when I'm trying to call `for()` loop there's a note `Unexpected token`.

```
public class ok {
    private int size;
    private static SizeLimit limit;

    private static final int arrsize = limit.getNumberOfSizes();
    private static int arr[] = new int[arrsize];

 for(int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++ ) { 

// Unexpected token (for()), Unknown class "arrsize", unexpected token (i++)
        arr[i] = limit.getLimit(i);
    }

    private Ship(int _size) {
        size = _size;          
    } 
 ...
```

Comment: Your code does not make much sense and your question is not clear. Please provide working code with a specific problem. For example, you have a lot of code that is not within a method. Also your method Ship has no return type... Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think my question is clear. I have problem with calling `for()` loop. `Ship(int _size)` is a private constructor

Comment: Why have you defined variable `i` as private in your for-loop?

Comment: I tried everything to make it work, but it didn't help. I removed `private`

Answer (score 0):

The ***private*** keyword should not be used for declaring a variable in the for loop:

```
  for(private int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++ ) {
```